# Record voice and Comparison prefab audio in unity

Tags: android, unityscript

I am android programmer that i Comparison Entrance voice with ready voice(prefab voice) for example when you say hello >>>>>to analyze>>>>>if your voice == prefab voice >>>>>you listen hello(play hello sound)
i want create game example tom that you can speak by somebody by speak.
[image]

i want scan Entrance words and i know about characters.
[image]

I want simulate artificial intelligence Robot speaks to you in android
how i can know about entrance words in android.
[image]

Comment: Huh? Can you try again to describe what it is you have, what you're trying to achieve and where, exactly, you're stuck? It's fairly difficult for me to tell what you're asking.